# Сломался xaml просмотр модели в конструкторе

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

При таскании проекта с одной версии студии на другую неожиданно сломался
Xaml просмотр модели в конструкторе

Вот собственно код:

```
<pg:BasePage x:Class="SLB.Pages.PageMain"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:pg="clr-namespace:SLB.Pages"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SLB"
      xmlns:res="clr-namespace:SLB.Properties"
      xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:SLB.Extension"
      xmlns:CtrlMh="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
      xmlns:CtrlZex="clr-namespace:ControlzEx;assembly=ControlzEx"
      Title="{x:Static res:Resources.SLBName}"
      FontSize="16"
      d:DesignHeight="600"
      d:DesignWidth="500"
      // Ругается на нижнюю строчку, недоступность ресурса
      d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Pages.PageMainViewModel}"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
```

При этом в 2010 студии это ещё работает. Нессображу, что там не так..

Comment: Пространства имен не менялись? Удалить строчку, скомпилировать проект и попробовать снова добавить, руководствуясь подсказками IntelliSence

Comment: Неа, ничего не менялось. Сейчас попробую...